# Unity 5: Check if an object's collider contains the mouse click point

Tags: unity

I am building a 2D turn-based RPG battle scene with Unity 5. The enemies are represented as 2D sprites with box colliders. In my script, the relevant enemy class is defined as:

```
public class EnemyView : MonoBehaviour {

    public SpriteRenderer _renderer;
    public BoxCollider2D _collider;

    void Awake() {
        _renderer = gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        _collider = gameObject.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D> ();
    }
}
```

And I have the following code grouping the enemy sprites together:

```
public class MainGUIView : MonoBehaviour {
    public EnemyView[] _enemyViews;
}
```

When a player clicks on an enemy, I would like to know the index of that enemy within the `_enemyViews` array. I thought of implementing this within `EnemyView` class but that class has no information about its index, so I am thinking of implementing `OnMouseDown()` within `MainGUIView` where I could iterate through `_enemyViews` to find the one whose collider contains the mouse click point, but I don't know how to write the code. Anyone can point me to some useful code snippet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Dictionary](http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary) to hold the index data.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

Dictionary<int, EnemyView> _enemyViews;
// populate dictionary

// element access while looping
_enemyViews[i].first;   // gets the index
_enemyViews[i].second;  // gets the EnemyView object
```

Comment: Thanks. I did it in another way by adding a field `public int _index;` to `EnemyView`

Comment: Or that. It's even the simpler way.